# Emulator does not start the activity

Tags: android, eclipse

Acording to console
"[2012-04-29 12:34:58 - Emulator] NAND: nand_dev_load_disk_state, restore failed: size required (705531195755904229) exceeds device limit (69206016)"

"[2012-04-29 12:34:58 - Emulator] savevm: unable to load section nand_dev"

[2012-04-29 12:36:35 - calc] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'my.calc.CalcActivity activity launch'!

Comment: It may be faster to create a new AVD than sort this out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close your eclipse and AVD both if needed create new AVD with different API and start again everything will be fine.

Comment: A very strange solution, but actually works!  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Open AVD Manager and go to the AVD that is failing to load. Highlight that AVD and choose the Start button. You should get a dialog box that allows you to choose to Wipe User Data. That should reduce the size of the saved disk cache, If this is your app you should check to see what your saving to disk.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, so I found, that emulator's minimum API level is less than my project's minimum API level. So I just changed minimum API level for project and I can run it without problems. Or you can change emulator's minimum API level.
I hope that can help you.

Answer (score 0):

No need to create AVD again no need to close eclipse again. Just go in the emulator settings>apps and uninstall the application last time you run on emulator(or in after which emulator get stuck).And than Run Application again from Eclipse(it may you require cancel emulator just after uninstalling the apps) because after you uninstall eclipse will load application again to emulator.